# 32/64 bits Issue with psr.exe

Tags: c, batch-file, cmd, 32bit-64bit

I currently have an issue with psr.exe. Actually, it works perfectly with the following command :

- C:\windows\system32\psr.exe
- C:\windows\syswow64\psr.exe
- psr.exe (with system32\cmd.exe and syswow64\cmd.exe).

BUT, it does not work when my program (a 32 bits program running on a 64 bits windows 7) use this bat to start the application. Nothing happens. 
My programm can open a notepad from a bat files, or execute whatever you want, but it does not work with psr.exe.

Can you give me some tips? Maybe it is not a 32/64 bits compatibility issue but I have other no idea about why this does not works...

EDIT : 
The batch file content is:
`C:\windows\system32\psr.exe`

The program running this bat is written in C, it uses this function to start it:

```
CreateProcessAsUser(
    hTokenDup,
    NULL,
    "C:\\toto\\mybat.bat",
    NULL,
    NULL,
    FALSE,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
    lpEnvironment,
    NULL,
    &sInfo,
    &ProcessInfo)
```

It works perfectly if the .bat file contains `C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe` instead of `C:\windows\system32\psr.exe`.

If I double click on my bat files containing `C:\windows\system32\psr.exe` from my desktop, it works perfectly, but from my C program, it does not work.

(NB : My c program works with other .exe files like notepad for example)

Many thanks.

Johan

Comment: could you add the code of batch file .

Comment: is it enough for you :) ?

Comment: information is enough but i am not able to figure why it is not working as i am in java only

Comment: some guy from my company work in my company in C, he is saying that C might fail in 64 and 32 bit problem

Comment: oh thank you. Tell him that windows event report this :Un périphérique ou programme a requis l’attention. Périphérique ou application : C:\windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe. Titre du message : C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe. Sorry for french....

Comment: Please learn how to format code properly: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: [`CreateProcessAsUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx) returns a `BOOL` (0 if it failed - from there you can use [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) to see the failure code). Also watch out on your _VStudio_ project _Build Platform_ ( _Win32_ vs _x64_). How do you wait on your sub-process? Could it be that _psr.exe_ has a special window type and returns immediately?

Comment: Please provide all your _C_ code. Have you tried running _psr.exe_ directly from _C_? I was able to run a simplified version of your project: running _psr.exe_ from a batch file form _C_ using [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What do you mean by "how do you wait on your subprocess"? What I do is just create a process as user using the function `CreateProcessAsUser`. It works perfectly if I use the `CreateProcess` function but then, PSR.exe is started in the "session0" because it is started by a service (my C program is called by a service).

Comment: 'CreateProcess` func family only starts the process which will run independently from your code (which will move to the next line), so it's not _blocking_. Here's an [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx) of dealing with these situations (`WaitForSingleObject` func) . Anyway, another piece of the puzzle was revealed, you run it form a service. Does that user have access to your desktop (where the _.bat_ file is located)?

Comment: Yes, the user has access to the desktop where the `.bat` file is located.

Answer (score 0):

If a 32-bit program running on 64-bit windows OS tries to access a file `C:\windows\system32\psr.exe`, Windows redirects the request to file `C:\windows\syswow64\psr.exe`.

To start a 64-bit system application from 32-bit environment you need to execute `C:\windows\sysnative\psr.exe` which will be redirected to "real" `C:\windows\system32\psr.exe`.

To run the bat-file entirely in a 64-bit environment, execute `C:\windows\sysnative\cmd.exe` with following parameters: `/c "C:\toto\mybat.bat"`

However, this does not appear to be a problem in your case.

Could it be that the user you are trying to impersonate has a corrupted profile, home folder, environment, or does not have some sort of privilege required by `psr.exe` application?

Or maybe the app requires user profile to be loaded but you didn't load it by calling `LoadUserProfile()` beforehand?

Try testing by running your batch file like this:

```
c:\windows\syswow64\runas.exe /noprofile /env /user:INSERT_USERNAME_HERE "C:\toto\mybat.bat"
```

Does it work? Now try removing `/env` and/or replacing `/noprofile` with `/profile`. Does it now?